# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_11_input to have shape (1, 1) but got array with shape (1, 3841)

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have tried various ways to reshape my data for a LTSM neural network but I continue to the get following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_29_input to have shape (1, 1) but got array with shape (1, 3841)
```

My original x_train data is shaped:

```
array([[-1.86994147, -2.28655553, -2.13504696, ...,  2.38827443,
         1.29554594, 46.        ],
       [-1.99436975, -2.41145158, -1.93463695, ...,  2.57659554,
         1.27274537, 68.        ],
       [-2.19207883, -2.24740434, -1.73407733, ...,  2.66955543,
         1.80862379, 50.        ]
```

**x_train shape: (1125, 3841)**

**x_valid shape: (375, 3841)**

**y_train shape: (1125,)**

So I've reshaped both my x_train and x_valid data (for predictions) in order to compile properly the model. I've looked at various examples with similar errors and they reshape it as seen below and they usually get their models working but in my case, I am not sure what is going on.

```
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
validX = np.reshape(x_valid, (x_valid.shape[0], 1, x_valid.shape[1]))
```

### Model Construction

```
def cnn_model():
    
    """"
    Creates the model of the CNN.

    :param nr_measures: the number of output nodes needed
    :return: the model of the CNN
    """
    # Initializing the ANN
    model = Sequential()

    # Adding the input layer and the first hidden layer
    model.add(Conv1D(64, 2, activation="relu", input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    # Adding the second hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    # Adding the output layer
    model.add(Dense(1, activation = "softplus"))
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam", metrics = ['mse'])

    return model
```

### Calling and Training Model

```
#Call Model
cnn_model= cnn_model(trainX)

#Train Model
history = cnn_model.fit(trainX, y_train, batch_size = 50, epochs = 150, verbose = 0 ,validation_data = (validX, y_valid))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the shape of `trainX` using following line

```py
trainX = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
```

it becomes
`1125, 1, 3841`.

Now when you have written following line

```py
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1, trainX.shape[1])))
```

The model expects `input_shape` to be `(batch_size, 1, 1)`.

You should have written

```py
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (1, trainX.shape[2])))
```

Now the model will expect `input_shape` to be `(batch_size, 1, 3841)` which will correspond to your new `tranX`.

On a side note, with sequence length/lookback/lag time of `1` and input features of `3841` , using LSTM does not really make sense because LSTM is designed to extract temporal features and here you have no temporal/historical data. Probably `Conv1D` layer will be more relevant before reshaping the input to `(batch_size, 3148, 1)` This is just a suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I was curious on a follow up question. I am still new to the field of deep learning and still trying to understand when trying to use a particular neural network for a specific regression case. Would something like the function I put in the question work? I updated the question with the CNN model I am thinking to use.